# Помогите решить задачу с детальным отображением данных элемента списка

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Есть две страницы. На первой (`index.xhtml`) отображается таблица, содержащая некоторые данные, например каталог автомобилей. Задача состоит в том, чтобы по клику на элемент записи открывалась бы другая страница (`surveydetails.xhtml`), с более детальными данными, содержащимим модель, марку и т.д..

Я не пойму как это реализовать средствами JSF? Что как и куда нужно передать с первой страницы, чтобы получить желаемый результат на второй?

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >
<h:head>
    <title>My first JSF programm</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="index">
        <h2>Hello  World!</h2>
        <p/>
        <h:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{surveyModel.surveys}" var="item" >
            <h:column headerText="Name">
                <h:commandLink  action="surveydetails" immediate="true">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**surveydetails.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >
<h:head>
    <title>Survey Details</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{surveyModel.surveys}" var="item" >
        <h:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Age">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.age}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton id="back" value="Back" action="index" />
</h:form>
<h:message for="back" styleClass="error"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**SurveyModel**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SurveyModel {

    private List<Survey> surveys;

    public SurveyModel() {
        surveys = new ArrayList<Survey>();

    }

    public List<Survey> getSurveys() {
        return surveys;

    }

    public void add(Survey survey) {
        this.surveys.add(survey);

    }
}
```

Comment: дайте глянуть бин

Comment: @evp добавил к посту

Answer (score 2):

в таком случае, когда бин SessionScoped - и вы обращаетесь из обеих страниц к нему одному, то, когда вы попадаете за первую страницу, создается класс, когда переходите на вторую, класс уже был создан и не создается повторно (он SessionScoped, один на сессию).
получается, в этой реализации можно ничего не передавать между страницами, просто находясь на первой странице у коммандлинка добавьте actionListener, он отработает раньше, чем action. В этом actionListener можно сохранить выбранную машину, а на второй странице читать именно ее (immediate не стоит устанавливать).

```
<h:commandLink  action="surveydetails" actionListener="#{surveyModel.setSelectedItem(item)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

в бине:

```
private Survey selectedItem; //getter+setter
```

ну и страница с деталями:

```
<h:outputText value="#{selectedItem.name}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{selectedItem.age}"/>
```

если же надо нужно именно передавать данные, тут сложнее:
1 Надо разделить бин на два, один с содержанием списка, второй - с конкретным surveyModel
2 в action надо указать метод и передать параметр (пусть будет name)

```
<h:commandLink action="surveydetails" >
    <f:param name="name" value="#{item.name}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

3. во втором бине, который содержит инфо о деталях, в конструкторе:

```
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
   this.name = params.get("name");
```

ну и дальше по имени находите тот элемент который пришел с параметром

Comment: А что такое `selectedItem` в commandLink?

Comment: да. ошибочка. там надо вставить #{surveyModel.setSelectedItem(item)}. Поправлю в ответе